# How to remove gaps between frames

Tags: html, dreamweaver

How to remove gaps between frames?

There were three frame. I want to clear those gaps.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>无标题文档</title>
</head>
<style>
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0
}
</style>
<frameset rows="*,18" cols="*" frameborder="no" border="0" noresize framespacing=0 margin:0;padding:0;border:0;>
  <frameset rows="*" cols="343,*" framespacing="0" frameborder="no" border="0">
    <frame src="UntitledFrame-2.html" name="leftFrame" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" id="leftFrame" title="leftFrame" />
    <!-- 2是左侧，1是右侧中间，3是下面的黑色。set-1是主文件  -->
    
    <frame src="Untitled-1.html" name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" title="mainFrame" />
  </frameset>
  <frame src="UntitledFrame-3.html" name="bottomFrame" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" id="bottomFrame" title="bottomFrame" />
</frameset>
<noframes>
<body>
<iframe src="http://IP:8090/" frameborder="no" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</body>
</noframes>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your frameset, you must add the `style` attribute propery

So change

```
<frameset rows="*,18" cols="*" frameborder="no" border="0" noresize framespacing=0 margin:0;padding:0;border:0;>
```

to

```
<frameset rows="*,18" cols="*" frameborder="no" border="0" noresize framespacing="0" style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;">
```

I also advice you to always close the html attributes with `"` for example `framespacing="0"` instead of `framespacing=0`